# POM file updated what to do next?

Tags: java, maven

I had a some config in pom.xml and now i have updated the version of a core tech... now should i run `mvn clean install` again or `mvn eclipse:eclipse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both.

If you are worried that you might trash something, take a recursive copy of your workspace before you do it.

---

Another alternative is to install and use the m2eclipse plugin.

Comment: Also, refresh your project in Eclipse after running mvn:eclipse:eclipse to make sure that everything is in sync/updated